# Adding a label to a scroll view in iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface

I would like to add a label to a scroll view. This is being done in main controller. However, when I do the following the label is on overlaying the contents of scroll view. I want the label to be exactly on top and then the rest of the scroll view contents.

```
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentView.frame.size.width, 80)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    label.text = @"Testing";

    [self.scrollView addSubview: label];
    [self.scrollView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: Can you be more clear on exactly what you want?

Comment: I want the label to appear directly on top of the scroll view...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is a little more to doing this programmatically. I'd highly recommend that you add this label to your xib or storyboard and not do this programmatically but if that isn't an option for what ever reason then there is only one thing you can do. You'll need to iterate over your scrollView's children and push each of the down slightly to make room for your new label, then set the label at the top of the scrollView.

Very simple example, this may not be working perfectly so you'll need to tweak it to what you need/want.

```
// Set the amount of y padding to push each subview down to make room at the top for the new label
CGFloat yPadding = 80.0f;
CGFloat contentWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.frame);
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){CGPointZero, contentWidth, 44.0f}];
label.text = @"Testing";

// Iterate over each subview and push it down by the amount set in yPadding. Also, check for the subview with the lowest y value and set that as your labels y so that it is at the top of the scrollView.
for (UIView* subview in self.scrollView.subviews) {
    CGRect subviewFrame = subview.frame;
    CGFloat currentLabelY = CGRectGetMinY(label.frame);
    // Set the labels y based off the subview with the lowest y value
    if (currentLabelY == 0.0f || (currentLabelY > CGRectGetMinY(subviewFrame))) {
        CGRect labelFrame = label.frame;
        labelFrame.origin.y = subviewFrame.origin.y;
        label.frame = labelFrame;
    }
    // Push the subview down by the amount set in yPadding
    subviewFrame.origin.y += yPadding;
    subview.frame = subviewFrame;
}
// Finally, add the label as a subView of the scrollView
[self.scrollView addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the label as a subview of the scrollview:

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:label]
```